# Install minikube (Kubernetes) because I have only one master server / node, but it is not pointing to my IP, but to IP 172.17.0.2

Tags: kubernetes, redhat, minikube

Good afternoon, I am new to Kubernetes and I am installing for the development environment Kubernetes, I have a red hat server(redhat) to be node/master, at the same time, I followed the following steps to install:

Following the tutorial on the page:

https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-kubernetes-k8s-minikube-centos-8/

```sh
sudo dnf update -y

sudo setenforce 0

sudo sed -i --follow-symlinks 's/SELINUX=enforcing/SELINUX=disabled/g' /etc/sysconfig/selinux

sudo systemctl start docker

sudo systemctl enable docker

sudo dnf install conntrack -y

#Installing Kubectl

sudo cat <<EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo (root)

yum install -y kubectl (root)

#Installing Minikube

curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64
chmod +x minikube
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin/
install minikube /usr/local/bin/
```

However, when I configure minikube, it does not point to the IP of my server, but to the IP 172.17.0.2:

[image: image1]

```sh
minikube ip

172.17.0.2

kubectl cluster-info
```

```
To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
The connection to the server 172.17.0.2:8443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

My IP is 10.154.7.209

What I can be doing wrong? If I can't use minikube to raise a server as master/node, what can I use?

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong . minikube is basically using the docker driver so `172.17.0.2` is the IP address of the container where your cluster is running.

But looks like you are using a [proxy somewhere in your system](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/vpn_and_proxy/). So you need to include the `172.17.0.0/24` range in the `NO_PROXY` environment variable.

Something like this:

```sh
export HTTP_PROXY=http://<proxy hostname:port>
export HTTPS_PROXY=https://<proxy hostname:port>
export NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,10.96.0.0/12,192.168.99.0/24,192.168.39.0/24,172.17.0.0/24 

minikube start
# get pods
minukube kubectl -- get pods --all-namespaces
```

✌️